# Can't seem to get a response from my SoapClient

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm just getting started with soap communication through php.

I have access to a webservice that returns a true or false dependant on three attributes 'username', 'password' and 'domain'

Here's my anonymised request code:

```
//VARS
$username = 'example';
$password = 'example';
$domain = 'example';

$client = new SoapClient("https://www.example.com/example.wsdl");

try {
    $client->authenticate(array($email, $password, $domain));
    echo $client->__getLastResponse();
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

die();
```

Now, as I mentioned, I'm new to this so I'm not sure that what I've written is even correct, please help!

Here are the relevant parts of the wsdl (again, anonymised):

```
//MESSAGE
<message name="AuthenticateRequest">
    <part type="xsd:string" name="username"/>
    <part type="xsd:string" name="password"/>
    <part type="xsd:string" name="domain"/>
</message>
<message name="AuthenticateResponse">
    <part type="xsd:boolean" name="authenticationResponse"/>
</message>

//OPERATION
<portType name="LDAPPortType">
    <operation name="authenticate">
        <documentation>
             Connects to the LDAP server with the parameters provided. If successful, this function then attempts to bind to the LDAP directory with the user's credentials. The function returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
        </documentation>
        <input message="tns:AuthenticateRequest"/>
        <output message="tns:AuthenticateResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
```

Have I missed anything crucial?
Thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are going to need `$username` instead of `$email` in this line

```
$client->authenticate(array($email, $password, $domain));
                             ^
```

Also try to specify parameter names in array as:

```
$client->authenticate(array("username"=>$username, 
                "password"=>$password, "domain"=>$domain));
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for spotting my error! Unfortunately I still cannot get a return. I used the parameter names as detailed in your above example. I'm not getting an error, or any Exceptions just nothing echoed to the page.

Comment: @DanielHanly: Try looking at the request you create by `echo "REQUEST: " . $proxy->__getLastRequest() . "";` after you call authenticate. you need to see page source to view this. Also save your return to a variable and print that as `$result = $client->authenticate(array("username"=>$username, 
                "password"=>$password, "domain"=>$domain)); print_r($result);` Also you should catch Exception instead SoapFault to see any other exception as `catch (Exception $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage ();
}`

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. The wsdl is https, would this affect the outcome? Where did the $proxy variable come from? I tried `echo "REQUEST: " . $client->__getLastRequest() . "";` but with no response, I get the word REQUEST though... Thanks for your help again.

Comment: @DanielHanly: yes having https for wsdl url affects. To see _lastRequest() you need to add 'trace' => 1 while creating soapClient as `new SoapClient( 
    'service.wsdl', 
    array( 
        'trace' => 1));`

Comment: Thanks Harry! The trace option was successful. Though I'm getting a false now, but I think that maybe due to incorrect credentials on my clients part. What adjustments do I need to make for https?

Comment: @DanielHanly if its working fine then you don't need any extra setting or might need to provide auth_cert and passphrase for https. But that's not the normal case.